# How can I stop asynctask in android when back button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am running an `AsyncTask` and it is taking a little time to load. In that period of time, if I am pressing back button then it does not respond. It responds only after a few seconds. So how can I kill or pause or override `AsyncTask` to go back? Or is there any other way to do something similar?

```
if (mainContent != null) {
    mainContent.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             Bitmap bmp = Utilities.getBitmapFromView(mainContent);
             BlurFilter blurFilter = new BlurFilter();
             Bitmap blurredBitmap = blurFilter.fastblur(bmp,1,65);
             asyncTask = new ConvertViews(blurredBitmap);
             asyncTask.execute();
         }
    });
```

My `AsyncTask`:

```
class ConvertViews extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        private Bitmap bmp;

        public ConvertViews(Bitmap bmp){
            this.bmp = bmp;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //Thread.sleep(200);
                if(mainViewDrawable == null) {
                    mainViewDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My `onBackPressed()`:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    asyncTask.cancel(true);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I am new to this platform. Can you tell me, how can I post the code? It is showing error while posting.

Comment: Copy and paste your code to the edit box, select all your code in the edit box, and press Ctrl+K to format it.  Then submit it.

Answer (score 2):

there is no way that you can stop a `asynch task instantly`.Every AsynchTask has a `boolean flag property` associated with it so if `cancel_flag =True` mean task has been canceled and  there is a `cancel()` function which can be called on a`asynchtask object` like this

`loginTask.cancel(true);`

but all this cancel() function does is ,it will set a cancel `boolean(flag )` property of asynch task to `True` so , you can check this property with `isCancelled()` function inside `doInBackGround` and do something ,like

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

and if it is True then you can use `break the loops`(if you are doing a long task) or `return`  to go quickly out of `doInBackground` and calling `cancel() on asynchtask` will skip the execution of `onPostExecute()`.

and the other option is ,if you want to stop multiple running asynch task in background then calling cancel on each one can be tedious so in this case you can have a boolean flag in `container class(of asynchtask)` and skip the working inside asynchtask if the flag has been set to True ,like

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (container_asynch_running_flag) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

but make sure to also put a check in `onpostExecute` in this case because it won't stop the execution of onpost.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop it instantly calling `asyncTask.cancel(true)`.

But it is not recommended to do because it can lead to memory leaks. Better to call `asyncTask.cancel(false)` and exit from doInBackground function manually checking `isCancelled()` value as @Pavneet advised.